# Bugzilla email_in.pl script will take 111 hours to complete - how can I change that?

Tags: scripting, perl

I have an old Bug tracking system, with about 20k bugs. We have installed a new bugzilla system, and part of the initiation will be to import all the bugs from the old system to the new.

I am able to use the email_in.pl process to read a file from an NFS shared folder (where I can save my CSV-->single files.

email_in.pl format http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.0/html/api/email_in.html
bug fields format http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.0/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#Create

However, while testing, each execution of the script takes rouglhy 20 seconds - rough estimation will be 111 hours for the entire database to import.

I am not very familiar with perl, and want to know is there a way I can actually make this happen in less time?
Has anyone had experiance with such?

*to note: i see that bugzilla is NOT a known tag here. Bugzilla is NOT the main issue. It's pure perl

Comment: 20 seconds *could be* 19 seconds for starting `/usr/bin/perl` and 1 second for processing your data...  [there are profiling possibilities for Perl](http://www.perl.org/about/whitepapers/perl-profiling.html), but I've never tried those.

Comment: I agree, and thanks. Looking into NYTProf (didn't know it's available). I am getting hard time making it work. will update.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the old data in let's say 20 sets and then run 20 imports in parallel. The linked page explains that even if something goes wrong (a race or format issue), you would be notified by a return mail, allowing you to fix these few miscreants later.